# Data not inserting in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a script for a guy and he uses Advanced Outgoing API (not familiar). He gives me this URL where the POST variable will be stored in `http://example.com/your_script.php?email_address={u_email}&firstname={u_firstname}`. So here is my php code. The problem is it cannot read the post values. When I echo it, it's empty.

NOTE: This is the instruction from the API Manual.

Advanced Outgoing API
You can have up to 5 URLs for each Product/Podcast/RSS Feed/Membership be notified whenever a subscriber event happens. You can enter these URLs by clicking on "Edit Notifications/Custom Fields" for a particular item. The system will then POST the following variables to the URLs you've entered. You can also include any of the variables below as a "tags" in your URL and the system will replace the tag with the actual value. This way you can post the values to an existing script that expects a variable name to be different than the ones listed below. For example, your notification URL could be: http://example.com/your_script.php?email_address={u_email}&firstname={u_firstname} . The system would then post all the variables below to: http://example.com/your_script.php?email_address=joe@example.com&firstname=Joe

```
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","xyz","xyz","xyz"); // Establish connection to insert in the first table.

    $username = $_POST['paypal_email']; // username of the user.
    $rawpass = $_POST['access_code']; // Raw password.
    $pass = md5($rawpass); // Password of the user encrypted with md5.
    $email = $_POST['email_address']; // E-mail of the user.
    $time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    echo $username;
    echo $pass;
    echo $email;
    echo $time;

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO wpinrootusers ('user_login', 'user_pass', 'user_email', user_registered, 'user_status') VALUES ('$username', '$pass', '$email', '$time', 0), $con"); // Insertion into wpinrootusers table.

    mysql_close($con); // Close connection.

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","xyz","xyz","xyz"); // Establish connection to insert in the second table.

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO customers ('receipt', 'prod_num', 'email') VALUES ('$rawpass', '6', '$email')", $con); // Insertion into customers table.

    mysql_close($con); // Close second connection.
```

Comment: Those aren't POST values. They are GET values. Also, don't use `MD5` for hashing passwords. It's broken. Oh, and mysql_* functions are obsolete. Oh, and you're wide open to SQL injections.

Comment: First your `mysql_connect` parameters are wrong and secondly why are you opening a connection twice to MySQL if you just need to insert into different tables (referencing this from the code comments)?

Comment: Yeah I see. But the thing is I cannot get the variables from POST. I inserted the API manual instructions.

Comment: Have you done a `var_dump()` of both POST and GET?

Comment: No I didn't. I put all the code inside my file here.

Comment: Well, what's there and in which global variable exactly?

Comment: I need to extract paypal_email, access_code and email_address from URL. By reading the manual API (which I pasted above), it's a POST method. But when I test it, it cannot read the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With mysql you have to do:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","xyz","xyz");
```

and then select the database:

```
$db = mysql_select_db("xyz");
```

The code you used to connect to database works with mysqli (i stands for improved) and you should consider switching from mysql to mysqli

Answer (score 0):

When you send the variable as GET parameters you have to use `$_GET` of course.